# Using hooks to set active className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to transform some of my class-component to functional-component.
but my "toogle" active class not working with hooks, please what am I doing wrong,  this is my script.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class ActiveState extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0
    };
  }

  handleOnClick = index => {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  };

  render() {
    const boxs = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    const box = boxs.map((el, index) => {
      return (
        <button
          key={index}
          onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, index, this.props)}
          className = {this.state.activeIndex === index ? "active" : "unactive"}
        >
          {el}
        </button>
      );
    });
    return <div className="App">{box}</div>;
  }
}
```

and this is what i tried using hooks , but not working :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function ActiveHooks() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = index => {
    setActiveIndex({ index });
  };

  const boxs = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  const box = boxs.map((el, index) => {
    return (
      <button key={index} onClick={handleOnClick} className= {activeIndex === index ? "active" : "unactive"}>
        {el}
      </button>
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{box}</div>;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = index => {
    setActiveIndex(index); // remove the curly braces
  };

  const boxs = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  const box = boxs.map((el, index) => {
    return (
      <button
        key={index}
        onClick={() => handleOnClick(index)} // pass the index
        className={activeIndex === index ? "active" : "unactive"}
      >
        {el}
      </button>
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{box}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks you @awran5 , its not working, i think i should add the binding like this : onClick={handleOnClick.bind(this, index)

Comment: There is no need for binding if you used [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments) syntax `() => ...` but why it's not working? have you test the code snippet above?

Comment: Can you make a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) example? here is a working [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-goldwasser-m52gd)

Comment: Why do i have to press twice for the color to appear? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  setActiveIndex(index);
```

Remove the curly braces. You updated your hook to {index: 1} instead of 1 if for example you clicked on 1.